# PHP Schedule with html tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a for-loop to output a 24 hour day via `<td>` cells. I want to retrieve my start time and end time from the database and display the `colspan` to represent the records in the database onto the table. I can successfully remove the extra `<td>` cells using the number of rows returned from the database, but I know there is a better way to output the `<td>` cells with `colspan` without repeating it via the number of rows.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZMbKILm.jpg]

```
// Interval in seconds
$interval = 1800;

$date_first     = "02-09-2013 00:00:00";
$date_second    = "03-09-2013 00:00:00";

$time_first     = strtotime($date_first);
$time_second    = strtotime($date_second);

for ($i = $time_first; $i <= $time_second; $i += $interval) {
    $timeOut = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("+30 minutes", $i));

    $a = $data->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $timeOut BETWEEN starttime AND endtime AND item = '1' AND active = 'true'");

    if ($a->num_rows > 0) {
        $b = $a->fetch_array();
        $starttime = $b["starttime"];
        $endtime = $b["endtime"];
        $colspan = $endtime - $starttime;
        // The items with colspan should be here
        // but they output too many times.
        // I need some way to exit this after each output.
        echo '<td colspan="'.$colspan.'"></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td></td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: 24 individual queries to the DB! Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

Set the next iteration correctly:

```
if ($a->num_rows > 0) {
    $b = $a->fetch_array();
    $starttime = $b["starttime"];
    $endtime = $b["endtime"];
    $colspan = $endtime - $starttime;
    // The items with colspan should be here
    // but they output too many times.
    // I need some way to exit this after each output.
    echo '<td colspan="'.$colspan.'"></td>';
    $i = $time_first + $interval*ceil(($endtime-$time_first)/$interval);
    // or, $i += $interval*$colspan;
} else {
    echo '<td></td>';
}
```

Comment: This solution creates a infinite loop. I'm wonder if there would be an easy way to accomplish this all together utilizing arrays?

Comment: It does? Strange. Try the alternate, `$i += $interval*$colspan`.

Comment: `$colspan = $endtime - $starttime` should be `$colspan = min(1, $endtime - $starttime)` to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But I think I need to take another direction. I can successfully get the colspan, my problem is I'm outputting to many results when I just need one.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your query. I'll mark this question as favorite so I can come back to it when it's not 7:30am

Comment: I think I will just build a class to handle the bookings and then pass them over to the loop instead of running 24 calls to DB. That is bad practice for sure. It's array time!!!! Thanks again Joe.

Comment: Well be sure to open a new question if you run into trouble with that query